# ASP case statement in .cs.aspx

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a web form that updates a SQL table.  The form is operating as expected.  I have run into a problem with some new users making incorrect entries (a user making a mistake go figure!)  I need to give the user the ability to reverse an entry.  What I wanted to do is simply put a check box on the form.  When the user hits the apply button, the system will either run a stored procedure that enters the information into the table or deletes the information from the table.  What I wanted to do is to use a case statement - if chboxReverse.True, run stored procedure 2 else run stored procedure 1.  I also want to reset the value to false after the stored procedure would be complete.

Here is the cs file information:

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=(local);database=InvoiceSHC;Trusted_Connection=Yes"))
    {
        // Get the UserId of the logged in user 

        string UserName = "";
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            UserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            UserName = "UnauthenticatedUser";
        }         

        string Timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        //Not sure why you need a SqlDataAdapter unused here.
        //SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter("UpdateSHCInvoice", con);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateSHCInvoice", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ref", dlRef.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhaseName", dlPhase.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageType", dlPageType.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Page", tbPage.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Percent", dlPercent.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChngType", dlChngType.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Timestamp",Timestamp);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", tbQty.Text);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        GridView1.DataBind();
```

What I would like to do is keep it all the same just change the stored procedure name based on the checkbox value.

Is this possible?

I am using Visual Web Developer 2008 Express and SQlServer 2008 R2

Comment: you have two different store procedure already in database

Comment: Having a SqlConnection in a Button_Click event is brutal code.  Please read this, and please implement at least 3 layers.  Presentation, BusinessLayer and DataLayer..........   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee817644(pandp.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You Can try like this...just add this  code from declaring sqlcommand cmd ...leave rest all the same...

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
if(chboxReverse.Cheked==true)
cmd.CommandText="NameofStoreProcedure2";
else
cmd.CommandText="NameofStoreProcedure2";
cmd.Connection=con;
```